# iOS - Empty blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I have a bizarre question. I made a mark up mistake earlier today which actually SOLVED a problem for me. The problem that it solved is irrelevant, my main question is... is this legitimate Objective-C? And why? Notice the empty block surrounding the second statement. I don't open the block with anything, no if, else, for, while, switch, etc. Any reason why this is working?

```
    if (condition) {
        statement;
    } {
    statement;
    }
```

Comment: I'd think it would be the same if you just omit those braces..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just add an empty block and `;` in Objective-C

```
{}
;
```

This both are OK.

Comment: Yeah, I've accidentally left single ; behind as well. Turns out that {} did NOT solve the problem I was having, like I thought. So back to the drawing board. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

reformatting:

```
if (condition) {
    statement;
}
{statement;}
```

As the others said: it's just extra pixels.